# Question About Banach's Fixed Point Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

Let $f:[3,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ defined as $x\mapsto \sqrt x$. Then for $ x,y \in [3,\infty)$ we have
$$ \left|\sqrt x-\sqrt y \right| =\left|\frac{x- y}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y } ~\right|\leq \frac 1 {2\sqrt3}\left|x-y\right|.$$

Hence $f$ is contraction on the complete space $[3,\infty)$. But clearly it has no fix point in $[3,\infty)$. What I am missing here?

Comment: $f$ should map $[0,\infty)$ into itself to make  Banach work. But $f(3)=\sqrt{3}<3$.

Comment: @Gary  Cant we use it on complete metric space?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger  But my example satisfy all the hypothesis . Then why we don't have fix point?

Comment: Your example doesn't satisfies all the hypothesis. The function need to be from $[3,\infty) \color{red}{\text{ to } [3,\infty)}$

Comment: @AdamRubinson It is a contraction, it is just not invariant.

Comment: @jjagmath  Yes . I didn't even noticed that in statement . Thank you !